# Linear Algebra Matrix to the third power is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can you guys think of any way to find a 2x2 matrix that when raised to the third power is the identity? I know there is the obvious answer of the identity itself, but I was specifically wondering about matrices that would take more than one elementary row operation to achieve. Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me some insight!

Comment: What about a rotation matrix

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of $2\times 2$ matrices of a particular form to represent complex numbers?  Then think about a complex number whose third power is equal to $1$.

Comment: $-e^{i {\pi \over 3}} I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $R_\theta$ be a matrix representing counterclockwise rotation in the plane by angle $\theta$. Show that $R_{\theta}^3 = R_{3\theta}$. What values of $\theta$ result in $R_{3\theta} = I$?

Comment: More generally, if $R_\theta$ satisfies $R_\theta^3 = I$ and $A$ is any other regular matrix, then $(AR_\theta A^{-1})^3 = I$ is also true.